# Syntax error on mysql but can't find where

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

I am doing a node js project to create database and add some seed in it 
but I got:

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const mysql_co = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "rootetna"
});

mysql_co.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mysql_co.query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS skigroo");
    mysql_co.query("CREATE DATABASE skigroo", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Database \"skigroo\" created.");
        mysql_co.query("USE skigroo");
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(errB, salt) {
            if (errB) throw errB;
            bcrypt.hash("hashtem" ,salt , function(errC, hash) {
                if (errC) throw errC;
                mysql_co.query("CREATE TABLE groups(`group_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`))ENGINE = InnoDB");
                mysql_co.query("CREATE TABLE users(`user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`phone_number` INT NOT NULL,`age` INT NOT NULL,`level` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`acess_token` VARCHAR(1300) NULL,`groups_group_id` INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `groups_group_id`),UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),INDEX `fk_users_groups1_idx` (`groups_group_id` ASC),CONSTRAINT `fk_users_groups1`FOREIGN KEY (`groups_group_id`)REFERENCES `skigroo`.`groups` (`group_id`)ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)ENGINE = InnoDB");
                mysql_co.query("CREATE TABLE events(`event_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,`groups_group_id` INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`, `groups_group_id`),INDEX `fk_events_groups1_idx` (`groups_group_id` ASC),CONSTRAINT `fk_events_groups1`FOREIGN KEY (`groups_group_id`)REFERENCES `skigroo`.`groups` (`group_id`)ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)ENGINE = InnoDB;");
                mysql_co.query("CREATE TABLE friends(`friends_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`accepted` TINYINT(1) NULL,`users_user_id` INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`friends_id`, `users_user_id`),INDEX `fk_Friends_users_idx` (`users_user_id` ASC),CONSTRAINT `fk_Friends_users`FOREIGN KEY (`users_user_id`)REFERENCES `skigroo`.`users` (`user_id`)ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)ENGINE =InnoDB;", (err, rows, field) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Tables "users", "events" , "groups" and "friends" created.');


                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO groups (name) VALUES ("grouptest1");');
                console.log("ça passe");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO groups (name) VALUES ("grouptest2");');
                console.log("ça passe");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO groups (name) VALUES ("grouptest3");');
                console.log("ça passe");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, phone_number, age, level) VALUES ("Valem", "test@test.test", ? , "0956321345" , "1" , "12", );',[hash] );
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, phone_number, age, level) VALUES ("stenvo", "stenvo_v@etna-alternance.net", ? , "0912121212" ,"4","14", );',[hash] );
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, phone_number, age, level) VALUES ("lottin", "lottin_s@etna-alternance.net", ? , "09143433" ,"9","24", );',[hash] );
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, phone_number, age, level) VALUES ("emery", "emery_a@etna-alternance.net", ? , "12345678" ,"123","99", );',[hash] );
                console.log("bug");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO events (name, description) VALUES ("test1", "event1");');
                console.log("bug");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO events (name, description) VALUES ("test2", "event3");');  
                console.log("OUI");
                mysql_co.query('INSERT INTO friends (accepted) VALUES ("1")');
                console.log("non");
                mysql_co.end();
                }); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The error output is Error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near ')' at line 1

Can't find why.

Comment: Your inserts to users end in `", )`, that comma is superfluous (or there needs to be data following it.)

Comment: Remove stuff until it works. Then put back what you recently deleted and tell us what the problem part is.

Answer (score 0):

Import the MySQL package.

var mysql = require('mysql');

Answer (score 0):

```
First import MySql library

const mysql = require('mysql');

And second instead of running multiple insert statement, run  single command as below.

var sql = "INSERT INTO groups (name) VALUES ?";

var values = [
['grouptest1'],['grouptest2'],['grouptest3']
];

  mysql_co.query(sql, [values], function(err) {

 if (err) throw err;

 });
```